# Image.grayscale(1.0) returns a full color image in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to convert an image to full grayscale with SwiftUI and am using `.grayscale()`.

The documentation says the following for this method:

> The intensity of grayscale to apply. Values closer to 0.0 are more colorful, and values closer to 1.0 are less colorful.

However, when I use `.grayscale(1.0)` a full-color image is returned but `.grayscale(0.99)` returns a full grayscale image.

Is this just a bug with SwiftUI or am I misunderstanding how this method works?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm guessing its a bug, but you can also use `.saturation(0.0)` and `.saturation(1.0)` to get the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error and I found this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/grayscale(_:)

Seems like you have to use 0.9995 instead of 1 to achieve the gray behavior.

[image: Gray Scale]